# mkdir fails in docker file but works fine when run manually

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, mkdir

I have a docker file that looks like this:

```
# escape=`
FROM  mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim
SHELL ["/bin/bash"]

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/myfolder
```

When I try to build that I get the following error:

> /bin/bash: mkdir -p /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/myfolder: No such file or directory

But if I start up an instance of the container with out that command then this runs just fine:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/myfolder
```

It makes the folder just fine.

I tried this as well:

```
RUN ["mkdir"] ["-p"] ["/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/myfolder"]
```

but that gives the following error:

> mkdir: missing operand
>   Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.

**How can I create a directory in a Linux container from my docker file?**

Notes:

- My machine is Windows 10
- My container is running Debian 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `SHELL ["/bin/bash"]` command was wrong.  When I remove that it worked fine.

Removing it or replacing it with `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]` seems to work.

Comment: The SHELL instruction allows the default shell used for the shell form of commands to be overridden. The default shell on Linux is ["/bin/sh", "-c"], and on Windows is ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]. The SHELL instruction must be written in JSON form.

The SHELL instruction is particularly useful on Windows where there are two commonly used native shells: cmd and powershell, including sh.

The SHELL instruction can appear multiple times. Each SHELL instruction overrides all previous SHELL instructions.

See also: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell